# Why I can't send sticker by it's id

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want my bot to send special sticker. I got it ID in logs after sending it to bot.

```
file_id "CAADAgADOQADfyesDlKEqOOd72VKAg"
```

This is what getUpdates give me
But if I try to send it, for example:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendSticker?chat_id=<id>&file_id=CAADAgADOQADfyesDlKEqOOd72VKAg
```

It responds"Bad Request: there is no sticker in the request". This is the code and it obviously does nothing:

```
def stickinmyass(bot, update):
    bot.send_sticker(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, file_id='CAADAgADOQADfyesDlKEqOOd72VKAg')
stickyass = MessageHandler(Filters.sticker, stickinmyass)
dispatcher.add_handler(stickyass)
j = updater.job_queue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `file_id` needs to be passed as the `sticker` parameter for the [sendSticker](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendsticker) method.

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendSticker?chat_id=<id>&sticker=CAADAgADOQADfyesDlKEqOOd72VKAg
```

or

```
bot.send_sticker(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, sticker='CAADAgADOQADfyesDlKEqOOd72VKAg')
```